# ASP.NET Changes in the sitemap file do not show up in the Design View for the Menu Control

Tags: asp.net, menu, datasource, sitemap, design-view

In my ASP.net site, I have a menu nicely styled control that works just fine on the local server.  It is linked to a SiteMapDataSource.

My trouble is that the Design View does not show the current menu structure.  Put differently, changes in the XML of the file MyMenu.sitemap do not show up in Design View, but they do show up when I run the program in debug mode.

I try refreshing the "Refresh Schema" link on the SmartTasks panel, both for the source and the menu control.  This does nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head: Temporary ASP.NET Files.

ASP.NET precompiles into a folder under Windows/Microsoft .NET called Temporary ASP.NET Files. Often times this is bane of a developers existence and where I would look if ASP.NET is doing something funky. Just delete everything out of the folder.

Have not done this in some time, so you may have to shut down Visual Studio to release all of the files. This is my first guess on the issue.

Comment: No Luck.  I found directories for Temporary ASP.NET files under ...\Framework\ as well as ...\Framework64\.  They still menus still do not update in design view.  Thanks for trying.